# curl to libcurl http put request in json format

Tags: json, http, curl, libcurl, arangodb

Currently I'm writing a program to interact with ArangoDB

Is there any way to send HTTP put request in JSON format using libcurl?

My current command in curl is

```
curl  -X PUT --data-binary @- --dump - --user "root:" http://localhost:8529/_db/myapp1/_api/simple/lookup-by-keys << EOF {"keys" : [ "FirstUser" ], "collection" : "five"} EOF
```

I would like to know the equivalent libcurl code to send the request above. Thanks

Comment: Did you set the content-type header? e.g. `curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json"`

Answer (score 1):

```
//PUT Request
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
long http_code;
static const char *jsonObj = //insert json here

curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

if(curl){

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "//insert your url here");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, (long)CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "root:");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, jsonObj);


    //enable to spit out information for debugging
    //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1L); 

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if (res != CURLE_OK){
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res) );
    }

    printf("\nget http return code\n");
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &http_code);
    printf("http code: %lu\n", http_code );


    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_global_cleanup();

    }
return 0;
}
```

This is the solution I come up with. Please feel free to add/improve

Answer (score 1):

I have the same kind of problem, and there is a curl arg which can help: --libcurl

```
curl http://example.com --libcurl example.c
```

It creates a c file, which will do the same as the command.
I found it there:
https://everything.curl.dev/libcurl/libcurl

It creates an absolute different way, compared to the suggestion i found, so let's learn from curl itself.